# error to drag and drop of charm to node

Tags: juju

I've received the following error when I try to make the drag and drop the service (munin) on the node 0

[image]

I've understoond that the problem is maybe the release used, but it's impossible to use the charm created for the previously release on new one??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Juju GUI doesn't allow you to place units on unsupported series and it looks like the `munin` charm only supports Trusty and Precise. If you want to force a unit of a different series onto the machine you have to do this via the CLI, although it's not recommended.

Comment: thanks, I thought Juju can deploy the charms on every type of Ubuntu and not only for that release. That could be a suggest to make JUJU more efficient.

Comment: Juju is technically capable of doing so however there is no guarantee that the charm will work, especially in this case when you're spanning systemd and upstart.